# stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stream

I'm using a network stream to read data from network in an `ASP.NET` application and I get this error while trying to read from the stream:

`stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations`

It happens sometimes. Any idea ?

Comment: a little code snippet would help identify the issue..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds simply as though you are trying to do two different operations on the same stream at the same time from different threads. Adding a `lock` (`Monitor`) or `Mutex` should help synchronise access to the stream.

Comment: This is by design. Some thread is reading data from net and write it to stream (it's inner stream, I use `HttpWebResponse`) and at the same time another thread reads the data. I thought this is because of concurrent reads or concurrent writes on the same stream (?). Should I uses a memory stream as a mediator ?

Comment: @Xaqron - accessing the same *stream* may be fine; but you still need to interleave/synchronize access; i.e. it shouldn't attempt to Read and Write **at exactly the same time**; RWRWRWRW should work, as should RRWRRWRRW, WWWRWWWRWWWRRRRWRWWWRWRW etc - the problem is attempting the two things **at the same instant**

Comment: After answering many of my questions with patience, I'm glad to do something for you, here it is: `\R/`